# ContinueWith delegate runs before the completion of Task

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, async-await, concurrentdictionary

Background info: I am trying to create a singleton class that will be able to process 5 concurrent operations at once. Each operation is represented by `SomeAsyncMethod`.

---

This method lives inside a singleton class.

`consumers` is a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,Task>`

My problem: for some reason the `ContinueWith` delegate runs before the completion of `SomeAsyncMethod`. The reason I know this is happening is because I have another method that watches `instance.Consumers.Count` - the count is `0` before `SomeAsyncMethod` is done.

Why is that?

```
    public bool TryAddDequeueRequest()
    {
        if (instance.Consumers.Count < 5)
        {
            Task bogusTask;
            Task newTask = new Task(SomeAsyncMethod);

            //RUNS AFTER THE REQUEST IS COMPLETED
            newTask.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                instance.Consumers.TryRemove(t.Id, out bogusTask);
            });

            //WE ADD THE TASK TO QUEUE
            instance.Consumers.TryAdd(newTask.Id, newTask);

            //SET IT AND FORGET IT
            newTask.Start();



            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it was not yet completed?

Comment: Added that detail. (The reason I know this is happening is because I have another method that watches instance.Consumers.Count - the count is 0 before SomeAsyncMethod is done.)

Comment: `SomeAsyncMethod` calls some service and updates the database. All done with `async` and `await` operations.

Comment: You should avoid having multiple threads each accessing shared memory.  The whole idea of the TPL is to avoid needing to do that by allowing tasks to use their results to pass information between threads.

Answer (score 2):

`SomeAsyncMethod`, if it's name is any indication, is an asynchronous method, presumably one that returns a `Task`.  You're creating a new task to *start* this asynchronous operation in another thread.  That `Task` will return when you finish *starting* the asynchronous operation, not when the asynchronous operation it starts finishes.

While you could unwrap the task, the easier option is to just not wrap it in a first place.  Call the continuation on the `Task` returned by the asynchronous method:

```
SomeAsyncMethod().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    instance.Consumers.TryRemove(t.Id, out bogusTask);
});
instance.Consumers.TryAdd(newTask.Id, newTask);
```

Of course, if you want to be able to perform some number of asynchronous operations with a fixed degree of parallelization, there are easier ways.  You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` to fairly trivially create a work queue of any fixed degree of parallelization:

```
public class FixedParallelismQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public FixedParallelismQueue(int maxDegreesOfParallelism)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreesOfParallelism);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SephamoreSlim blocks. `When the count reaches zero, subsequent calls to one of the Wait methods block until other threads release the semaphore.`

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky Good thing I'm not calling `Wait` then, isn't it.  This code does not block, it is entirely asynchronous.

Comment: even if you do `WaitAsync` - it creates a backlog of requests. I want those requests NOT to backlog and to go away if the "processors" are busy.

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky Then you don't need pretty much anything at all.  Just have an `int` to keep track of the number of pending operations.  If it's below the limit, increment, run, and decriment in the continuation.  If it's at the limit, do nothing.  Done.  Of course, if the caller is just going to be continuing to try to queue items over and over you're better off just queuing items above the limit in an actual queue, like this.  If they really do want the operation to be dropped on the floor, then I guess that's what you want.

Comment: you're right I could do it that way - but integers are not thread safe. How would you go about making them thread safe?

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: Ok. I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SomeAsyncMethod` is asynchronous, it returns before finishing its *own* task.

If you have control over the code for `SomeAsyncMethod` then refactor it to be synchronous (no `await`/`async`), or if there is already a non-asynchronous version, then just use that.

If you don't have control over the method's code, you can wait for it to finish in the surrounding task before continuing:

```
Task newTask = new Task(()=>{ SomeAsyncMethod().Wait(); });
```

Comment: The solution is to *not wrap it in a task at all* not to schedule a thread pool thread to start a task, synchronously wait on it, and then set the task's result.  That's just silly.

Comment: @MarkCidade Your edited proposal is equally insensible.  Why would you go out of your want to use a synchronous version of an operation and create a new thread just to sit there and wait for it instead of using an inherently asynchronous implementation of the operation?  It avoids the need to have a thread sitting there doing nothing.  The solution is to not wrap the task in another task at all, not to find some way of making the asynchronous code synchronous.